# How to add optional delegates with #if canImport() enabled?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, protocols

how to add optional delegates between **#ifCan** compiler tags?

Here what I need t do:

```
#if canImport(optionalFramework)
//adding optional delegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, OptionalDelagate
#else
//no need for delagete
    class ViewController: UIViewController
#endif
```

Such feature if possible would really be crucial and would really improve whole application design.. However, I am getting **multiple compiler errors.**.

I tried to create separate class,which would use this delegate, but **I can't remove it**, and  I am getting memory leaks, because of strong references.

Thanks as always :)

Answer (score 1):

Move the delegate definition into an extension:

```
#if canImport(optionalFramework)
extension ViewController: OptionalDelegate {

}
#endif
```